# If $f$ is continuous function and $g(x):=f(x)\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ given $g$ is non-increasing. Prove that $f(x)=0$, for all $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

How can I prove this problem?

> If $f$ is a continuous function and $$g(x):=f(x)\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$given $g$ is non-increasing. Prove that $f(x)=0$, for all $x$.

**My attempt**:
Since $f(x)$ is a continuous function, so $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)$ is differentiable and hence $f$ is differentiable and since $$g(x)=f(x)\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$so $g$ is differentiable because is the product of differentiables functions. Now, we can differentiating both sides gives $$g'(x)=\left(f(x)\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\right)^{'}=f'(x)\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt+f(x)f(x)=f'(x)\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt+f^{2}(x) \iff f'(x)\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt+f^{2}(x)=g'(x).$$Now, since $g$ is non-increasing, $g'(x)\leq 0, \forall x \in Dom(g)$ and hence $$f'(x)\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt+f^{2}(x)\leq 0 \iff  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \quad f'(x)\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\leq -f^{2}(x)$$

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. But is there any way to use my attempt to prove the result?

Comment: $\int_\limits{0}^x f(t)dt$ differentiable does not imply that $f(x)$ is differentiable too, otherwise all continuous functions would be differentiable and it is evidently false.

Comment: Sure, you're right. Thanks so much.